# Setting session variable from foreign key in Django: Need field name instead of primary key

Tags: django, session, foreign-keys, primary-key

I think this should be simple, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.  I'm setting a session variable based on a foreign key/ drop down in the template.  The session variable saves as the primary key instead of the field name.  How do I change this?

models:

```
class Verbs(models.Model):
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.verb

class MyVerbs(models.Model):
    verb = models.ForeignKey(Verbs)
```

forms:

```
class MyVerbForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta: 
    model = MyVerbs
```

views:

```
def TestSession(request):
request.session['myverb'] = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyVerbForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        myvariable = form.cleaned_data['verb']

    #myvariable = request.POST.get('verb', '')
    request.session['myverb'] = myvariable
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = MyVerbForm(request.POST)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('test.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

def Session(request):
    myvariable = request.session['myverb']
    context = {'myvariable': myvariable}
    return render_to_response('base.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 0):

You should call `form.is_valid()` then get the value from `form.cleaned_data` rather than `request.POST`.

Comment: The page now loads, but when I submit, I now get the following error:<Verbs: go> is not JSON serializable

Comment: Well, then there's some code you're not showing, as you're not doing anything with json in the code you have shown.

Comment: This is pretty much the sum of my site. It is actually just a simple site I'm working on to learn how to what I need to do.  I'm very new at this btw.   Thanks again! @daniel-roseman

Comment: I modified my original to what is current.